# What is the logic of minimum 15 minute Interval in AWS DataPipeline Scheduling?

Tags: amazon-web-services, real-time, amazon-rds, data-integration, amazon-data-pipeline

I recently was asked to build a mechanism to get data from our RDS MySQL in near real time i.e within 5sec. to 5min. After reading Lambda, Flydata and Data Pipelines I selected AWS **Data Pipeline** as so many forums mention its name when it comes to near real time data ingestion.

AWS Data Pipeline lets us Schedule the job so I selected scheduling option and set it to run every 2 minutes.

[image]

Here comes the ugly part. **It asked me to set an interval period also!!** which should be greater than 15 minutes. I mean why would it? Isn't it supposed to be near real time?
Now when I ran my Pipeline It worked like this. (After setting interval of 15 minutes)[image]

How is that supposed to be near real time?? I mean do AWS realize that near real time means **within seconds**, or at-least **some**minutes but 15-17 minutes are a huge set back for me. Can someone tell me how to over come that problem. I thought about scheduling multiple pipelines and setting preconditions but I am not sure that it will work.
 please Help...

Comment: Have you read this? https://blogs.aws.amazon.com/bigdata/post/Tx37EJ2IDFXITB2/Introducing-On-Demand-Pipeline-Execution-in-AWS-Data-Pipeline

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend Amazon Kinesis for working with real time data.

https://aws.amazon.com/kinesis/firehose/

Comment: That way, I would have to make an application which will poll RDS every minute to see if new data came and then send it to Kinesis Stream. What if I don't want to involve in Application development right now?